# Attempt to index field '?' (a nil value) - error

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code but what I'm trying to achieve is to have regular spawns of blocks scroll past the screen which the player has to dodge. when each block goes off the left hand side of the screen, it increases the 'obstacle values +1'

The problem I have is that when my 'block' object goes off screen I get this error:

"Attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)"

can anyone help me because I really am stuck. 
thanks

```
local yPos = {50,110,200}
local speed = 6
local block = {}
local obstacles = 0


function createBlock(event)
  local rnd = math.floor(math.random() * 4) + 1
  b = display.newImage('images/block3.png', display.contentWidth, yPos[math.floor(math.random() * 3)+1])
  b.x = 480
  b.name = 'block'
  physics.addBody(b, "static")
  blocks:insert(b)
  print(b.x)

  return true

end

function gameLoop( event )
   if(blocks ~= nil)then
     for i = 1, blocks.numChildren do
      blocks[i].x = blocks[i].x - speed -- (( THIS IS THE LINE WHICH GENERATES THE ERROR))
       if(blocks[i].x < -0) then
         display.remove(blocks[i])
         blocks[i] = nil
         print("+1!!")
         obstacles = obstacles +1
       end
     end 
  end
end


timerSrc = timer.performWithDelay(900, createBlock, 0)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", gameLoop)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are calling `display.remove(blocks[i])` which is fine, but in the line right after you are setting `blocks[i]=nil`. There is no indication from the corona docs that this is a valid operation.

Also, once the object has been removed it is no longer in the group, so for sure doing `blocks[i]=nil` is incorrect: you are probably nilling the next block! I can't check here but it would be interesting to print the id of the object i being deleted in this loop, before and after. You probably find that before executing `display.remove(blocks[4])` (picking i=4 so example is clearer) the blocks[4] is not same object as after, so in effect you are removing two objects (and the second one is being removed incorrectly).

If `blocks` were a regular table rather than a userdata, the issues would be different, but you'd still have issues (beyond scope of your question; but I recommend you try it out!).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in off screen object. When object is moving out of the visible group then it's became nil. So you can't not access that object.
You need to define alpha = 0 or isVisible = false of that object before moving out of the viewable screen and then you can access that object.

Answer (score 0):

You would get that error if you are "out of bounds," per se. If you try to run your code, but try to access an index in table `blocks` that is `nil` then you will get that error.

My guess is that it has something to do with the `numChildren` thing you have going on there. Not really sure where that comes from, but I suggest using the default `#` operator to measure the size of the table.

For example:

```
for i = 1, #blocks do
    ...
end
```

Or even use an iterator:

```
for i, block in ipairs(blocks) do
    ...
end
```

Another possibility is that your `blocks:insert()` method is not inserting the values in order, starting the insert at 0, or not even using numerical indices (doubt that though).

In that case, I would suggest using the standard `table.insert(blocks, b)`